# laravel get data to pass to laravel blade but in json format

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have data that I am creating a chart using d3.js.  I have that part working with hard coding the data as such

```
var data = {
            "name": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            "vals": [48, 35, 34, 21, 11]
        }
```

Where I am struggling is to get data into the javascript section of my blade template.  I have tried to hardcode the following and I get an htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

```
$test = json_encode([
            "name" => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            "vals"=> [48, 35, 34, 21, 11]
        ]);
```

with this in the script area of the blade

```
var test = {{json_decode($test)}};
```

If I don't do json_decode I don't get an error but it transforms my " to &quot which obviously won't work.

I know I am just missing something here to make it work but maybe I will just do a new method and do an ajax call to get it.

Any thoughts or tips would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to output the value unescaped - `var test = {!! $test !!}`.

And if you're getting your values from a database or model, you could consider using the `toJson()` helper.

Comment: Knew it was something simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Simply use unescaped output:

```
<script>
    var array = {!! json_encode($array) !!};
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
    var array = @json($array);
</script>
```

Both variants in PHPStorm will highlight this line with an error - expression expected

So, my complete answer is:

```
<script>
    var array = [].concat(@json($array));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

@fubar's solution worked for me. With one small change. The solution `@json($geoJson)` did not.  But that was because I didn't put an array into the function but already a string. I had to extend @fubar's approach for me:

```
const data = JSON.parse(' {!! $geoJson !!} ');
console.log('data', data);
```

The single quotes were important.

Comment: Crazy! I looking for a solution and found my own answer! *lol / And it helps me ...

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach in the latest Laravel 9 is:

```
<script>
    var app = {{ Js::from($array) }};
</script>
```

It uses the `JSON.parse(...)` approach under the hood. Same as in the answer of @Maik Lowrey

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json